# while sending the mail using smtplib in python got the error (11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')

Tags: python-3.x, sendmail, smtplib

I'm sending a mail using a python script on a development server which don't have internet connection but i check the connectivity with the SMTP server by pinging the server and it is connected. But i'm getting error (11004, getaddrinfo failed) while connecting to it using smtplib.

Please help me in this issue!
Below is the code im using

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = "sender"
msg["To"] = 'recipient'
msg["Subject"] = "Testing Email"
message = 'Hi,\n \nThis is testing mail.'
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
   ctype = "application/octet-stream"
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)
fp = open(file, "rb")
attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename='report.xlsx')
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
msg.attach(attachment)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server_name)
    server.set_debuglevel(0)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.google.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
server.sendmail(email, email, message)
server.quit()
```